# Custom content in a TextBox/RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, richtextbox

I want the user to be able to add footnotes/annotations to a TextBox/RichTextBox. These should show up as small icons that the user can hover their mouse over and click to get additional info. These annotations should flow with the text. Is there any way to do this with the TextBox/RichTextBox control? If not, is there any third party solutions available?

Comment: You can add any child control you want to an [`InlineUIContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for instance a button, then add that to the [`Inlines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span.inlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of some parent [`Span`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks dbc, I decided to use AvalonEdit a free richtexteditor with ways to transform regex-matched text into inline elements, as well has having nice performance.